# How to stop converting Viram '।' symbol into code on blogger post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, type-conversion, blogger

**I want to convert "." into "।" that is a Hindi full stop Symbol or Character**

I am using the bellow script to convert "." into "।" which is the Hindi Stop symbol. I am using this code in a blogger post, This code gives me code like below

```
&#2404;
```

[The code thrown on blogger Platform by this Following Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Ox3.png)

When I am using Pipe | in place of ।, it works perfectly and there is no error. But Pipe "|" is not the right symbol for a full stop in Hindi.

Kindly Suggest converting "." into "।" for a blogger like similar code

Please Correct me If I am wrong. I Love Blogger but I don't have much knowledge of JavaScript and Jquery.

I have used  some bellow code but it did not work

```js
$('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  var str = val.replace('.', '।');
  $(this).val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Your code works when the `type="text"` is removed. There is no type="text" on a textarea. I am voting to close

Comment: Your code is working perfectly maybe other things are conflict with your side.

Comment: This code is working fine here but does not work on the blogger.com blog post. this code also works on many editor like w3schools etc

Comment: @mplungjan, sir why is the above code is not working on the blogger post area and through an error &#2404;

Comment: Perhaps the codepage is not UTF8?

Comment: @mplungjan,
Sir I have used  some bellow code in Head Section but it did not work
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>

Comment: @mplungjan,
Sir,
The following Code is present in the theme

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

I have tried adding Some Libraries And Code like but the same error

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'/> 
    <meta charset='UTF-16'/>
    <meta charset='ISO-8859-1'/>
    
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'/>

Please check the [link](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html)

Comment: @mplungjan 
Sir, Please Check the [Link] 
(https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html)

Comment: Ah, sorry! Missed that I had to type

Comment: So the page is NOT in UTF8. It is is `<meta content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>` AND 
`<meta content='text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`

Comment: You need to go into your server files and remove those two lines

Comment: @mplungjan 
Not Worked Sir, ON Blogspot Blog after removing above 2 files from theme 
It Works Fine on WordPress Blog Also [Link](http://examstrick.com/index.php/2021/10/26/hsqbnhw-hwd-dw-xwh/)
but I need it on BlogSpot [Link](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html)
I am very much thankful for supporting here and diagnosing the issues

Comment: @mplungjan, Around a month, have been passed on struggling but  seeking a solution

Comment: Very strange. You also load jQuery twice by the way. remove `<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Comment: @mplungjan, oh sorry. I am removing it

Comment: Can you change the headers to `<html dir='ltr' lang='en-GB'><meta charset="UTF-8">` ?

Comment: instead of `<html dir='ltr' lang='en-GB' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
<head>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>`

Comment: @mplungjan, Sir, It is not remove=ing, It's by default on Blogspot. Is there any other alternative

Comment: Try creating a page with only the utf8 header, textarea and the script

Comment: @mplungjan, Sir, Please Suggest me the code

Comment: @mplungjan
Sir, Is there any JS or Jq Code code that works fine for Converting (.) into "।" without removing the default below Code on the blogger

<html b:defaultwidgetversion='2' b:layoutsVersion='3' b:responsive='true' b:templateUrl='indie.xml' b:templateVersion='1.3.3' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' expr:lang='data:blog.locale' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>

Comment: The code you have works. We need to stop the platform from converting to html entities

Comment: @mplungjan, 
Please add appropriate code in the code to stop converting to html entities

Comment: I have no other suggestions

Comment: @NearHuscarl,
Sir Please have a look at the problem. It's working here but fails on the platform [Blogger](https://mmininninnn.blogspot.com/2021/10/jbb-jlk-k.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try a page with JUST this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir='ltr' lang='en-GB'>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test page</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('textarea').on("keyup", function(e) {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var str = val.replace('.', '।');
        $(this).val(str);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <textarea></textarea>
</body>

</html>
```